# How to get the MJPEG stream from a NC541 camera?

Tags: mjpeg, ip-camera

I have an NC541 IP camera, which supposedly does have an MJPEG stream, as in the manual it says "The video is compressed by MJPEG", but I can not find a way of how to get that stream from the camera. Seems that it wants to work only with the build-in program, while I need the way mjpeg stream instead.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use network sniffer such as Wireshark to find this out, or check with the manufacturer for SDK/API docs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this camera, but on many you can simply right click on the video window in your browser, select properties, and it will tell you the URL of the raw stream.  If this is a multi codec camera you may or may not get the mjpeg stream depending on which one is chosen for the camera's home page.  This often works for me.